# How to explicitly pass type arguments to generic functions in flow?

Tags: generics, flowtype

I'm trying to explicitly specify the type when calling a generic function.

For example:

```
export function gen<T>(a: string): { eat: T => string } {
  return {
    eat: (v: T): string => a
  };
}
```

Of course, using C++-like syntax doesn't work, because flow extends Javascript syntax, and this is already a valid JS expression (a comparison):

```
const { eat } = gen<number>("str")
```

**What is the correct syntax?**

I want to pass a type explicitly, because otherwise this sort of code won't produce an error:

```
const { eat } = gen("str")
const a = eat(5)
// I want this to be an error, but it is not
const b = eat("foo")
```

I can of course annotate the assignment, causing the desired generic type to be inferred, but that can be cumbersome. [Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgLJwCYCuMApmAILrEAeADnAE4AuYUBAdgMaMCWcbYAc2JsAPABUAfAAoAhgC4wAZ0b1ubAQEoFAbzDEZjBWLABeCUpVqBYAL5htqMGHrFGBevwdOn+w2CkAbkZaFqrqpuYyjrYA3Kg26Jg4+ESkAEKJWAAicMSKbADkzAgMANZgAEbEHDIEiqTcjAWKYDJgHHAAtjQyqop8GFgdbMr2ega2poLCImwEnVX00gBEyvTLGujDo7q+kybTbFKrKhuovlIArJtJAJJgCDJszIwAFtwtjHCVpE969PQGAAaSoEZiNMAfMBsOCMc4GY5QOBwM6DVpsGGMAxWMBvX6KRTcARsTrCZg1fhVdrzRb9Un+J54SEtTFgOgE7gVEgPRqvOBg9GtDnE0nPTbbZi7AwKUkTGw6cZ+OYLYj0CKhHF2A5CI7LCq9VGyxhSAAMVDw+jwNywABIAKK0aqMO0Ahhoo3HL4ozZAA)

Comment: Seems to be not possible with flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is able since v0.72. [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Changelog.md#0720). [Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAmBTAxtAhgJzaJAK4B2GALgJawmgC22A1mgGKywA8AKgHwAUASgBcoLgG5kGGgGdyoOQF56TVuw4kidAEZpc-ARMR9yIjdt0HkIUABIAogA8ADpnJ3cuWLiMnQs3JQkAOYGQA)

```
// @flow

declare function makeFoo<T>(): T;

const t = makeFoo<number>();

(t: number);

// $ExpectError
(t: string);
```

Comment: Wow, we had updated already but must have missed that in the changelog. Thanks. I'm surprised they added it in a way that hijacks existing JS syntax though.

Answer (score 1):

Generics can be used for specifying a relation between arguments or arguments and a result. You can`t use it at "call time", only on declaration.
It makes you write more unmistakable code - it`s better to have 2 functions than one universal (from point of understanding and typing):

```
function eatNumbers(v: number): string {return "" + v;}
function eatSomething<T>(v: T): T {return v;}
```